# SkypeForBusiness Call in Citrix (Windows Client, Ubuntu host) calls get disconnected

Tags: 20.04, skype, citrix

In my work Environment we have **Windows Clients / Virtual Machines** which we connect to via **Citrix Workplace**.

After some updates on my **Ubuntu 20.04 Host** - **Skype For Business** Calls in Citrix get disconnected due to network issues.

In `var/log/kern` I see this lines - every 20 minutes:

```
Jan 31 10:55:43 myPcName kernel: [16411.401908] RTMediaEngineSR[14447]: segfault at 10 ip 00007fa8044ae33a sp 00007fa8012f0710 error 4 in libc-2.31.so[7fa8043d3000+1e7000]
```

At the same time where the SkypeForBusiness Call get disconnected due to network issues.

PS this seems the same issues as in the  [Linux Mint Forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=311762)

Answer (score 0):

**On the [Citrix Download for HDX_RealTime_Media_Engine_2.9.400_for_Linux_x64](https://www.citrix.com/de-de/downloads/citrix-receiver/additional-client-software/hdx-realtime-media-engine-29400.html)

Install the current HDX_RealTime_Media_Engine_2.9.400_for_Linux_x64.zip** 
The issues was was supposed to be fixed in version 2.9.200 (as mentioned by Daniel Venema on the [Citrix Discussions](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/406924-rtmediaenginesrv-core-dumps-on-linux-mint-193-ubuntu-1804-bionic/page/2/#comment-2087605)

**Be aware** that a Goolge search may point you to [latest Current Release version](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/additional-client-software/hdx-realtime-media-engine-latest.html) which (in my case did hold the **out-dated** version 2.9.0) that **does not include the fix**